# Migration Required for blank Sensitive Properties Key [nifi.sensitive.props.key]

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a docker file for creating an image for Apache NiFi 1.22.0, and it is inspired by the official [docker file](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.22.0/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile)(for my work, I have made some adjustments, like GID, volumes etc.).

The container launches fine and the app is working fine, the first time.

But if I stop the container and launch a new container, I get this issue:

```
2023-08-28 03:01:14,845 ERROR [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Flow Configuration [/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flow/flow_configuration/flow.json.gz] Found: Migration Required for blank Sensitive Properties Key [nifi.sensitive.props.key]
2023-08-28 03:01:14,845 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There was an issue decrypting protected properties
```

To get it working again, I have to remove all volumes.

On some Google search, I found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8943). But my start.sh file already have this(as suggested by fix):

```
if [ -n "${NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY}" ]; then
    prop_replace 'nifi.sensitive.props.key' "${NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY}"
fi
```

What may be going wrong in my case?